# Where is cassandra installed on mac? How to check the version?

Tags: cassandra

I've installed cassandra on my mac. 
How do i check the path where it is installed? 
Also, How can i check the cassandra version installed on my mac?

Comment: How did you install cassandra?

Answer (score 1):

How did you install cassandra? You haven't given any information.

In general, in MAC you can download it as a binary. 
So starting it would be by running /bin/cassandra

You can know the version from running cassandra by connecting it via CQLSH.
The prompt displays the version of cassandra it connected to.

You can find CQLSH at /bin/cqlsh

Answer (score 1):

This is old, but if you don't know where you installed cassandra on your Mac then you can always do:

> sudo find / -name "cassandra"

You will get a list of paths (if you have more than a single instance)... something like:

> /usr/local/bin/cassandra

Once you know the location of your Cassandra instance(s) you can simply execute the cassandra binary with the -v option.

> /usr/local/bin/cassandra -v

*Note: the path above is likely to be a link. Your find call should acquire all instances exist on the system when used with sudo.*

Answer (score 0):

I installed cassandra with homebrew and in that case Cassandra bin folder was at following location,

> /usr/local/var/homebrew/linked/cassandra/bin